# Get minute average of value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using this query to get the hourly average of a value and it seems to work fine.

```
select Time_Stamp_Hour = dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,Time_Stamp), cast(CAST(Time_Stamp as date) as datetime))
      ,AvgValue = AVG(Value)
from ValueLog
group by dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,Time_Stamp)
        ,cast(CAST(Time_Stamp as date) as datetime))
```

I need to get by minute averages for the whole day, so one day's returned results should have 1440 records.

I have tried switch the hh to mi, but it just gives me the average of 60 individual minutes for the whole day without the by hour breakdown each day. How would I convert this statement to the minute averages for every hour in the day. I am using sql server 2012.

[image: sample result when using mi instead of hh]

The hour column does not return the correct hour(just shows 00) when using mi instead of hh and the above statement and I only get 60 results per day.

Here is an example of when I run the above statement with hh as my condition, which the results show correctly.

[image: hh]

Comment: What do you mean by "the minute averages?"

Comment: Can you include add a [MCVE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) to this question?

Comment: I have a table that has two columns, time-stamp and sample value ,which gets recorded every few seconds. I can use the above select statement to get the hourly average of those samples. I need to take this a step further and get by minute averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truncate the seconds from the timestamp, use: `dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)`

```
select Time_Stamp_Hour_Minute = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)
  , AvgValue = avg(Value)
from ValueLog
group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)
```

---

You could also replace the expression in your question to truncate by hour to `dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)`.

---

Using `convert(varchar(5),time_stamp,8)` will return the time as `hh:mi`, which is what it sounds like you are trying to do. Style `8` returns the format `hh:mi:ss`, and converting it to varchar(5) limits it to the first 5 characters (`hh:mi`).

```
select Time_Stamp_Hour_Minute   = convert(varchar(5),Time_Stamp,8)
      , AvgValue = avg(Value)
from ValueLog
group by convert(varchar(5),Time_Stamp,8)
```

reference: [`cast()` and `convert()` styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I think you gave me the answer i was looking for with truncating seconds and milliseconds off my timestamps. This should allow me to run if statement against other conditions i have in the database. This is a different way of attacking the problem, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "TWA" time weighted average, Check this monster out. I built this for an interface for my SCADA package. With this query you are not limited to standard 1 min, 1 day, 1 hour intervals. You can change the @i to get what ever interval you want. The main job of the query is to handle missing intervals if they exist in your table. I.E if you had a value at 1AM but didn't have another value until 8AM... ect...

NOTE: Remove the final select statement and make COMBINE your final select statement to see what is going on. You can copy and paste the below directly into SQL Server and run with no changes.
In your case change @i to equal 1, Good luck.

```
--Create the test table! Add any values you want!
DECLARE @TEST001 TABLE ( Time_Stamp datetime, TagA INT, TagB INT, TagC INT, TagD INT, TagE INT, TagF INT ) 
-- Insert test Values so we can test what is going on with the monster query below.       
 INSERT INTO @TEST001
 VALUES
    ('2017-01-21 00:01:09.042', NULL, NULL, NULL, 7000, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:02:03.042', NULL, NULL, 87,   NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:04:10.155', NULL, 1239, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:04:10.959', NULL, NULL, 86,   NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:06:49.401', NULL, 1240, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:06:59.301', 100,  1239, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:07:00.000', 109,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:07:10.124', 108,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:12:11.789', 109,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:16:12.190', 108,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:16:13.987', 107,  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:17:31.410', NULL, 1260, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:17:32.511', NULL, 1261, 87,   NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:17:32.966', NULL, 1262, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('2017-01-21 00:18:53.140', NULL, 1262, NULL, NULL, 6000, NULL)

-- Begin of our query. NOTE to Tech's, The above is not needed WHEN using real table data.
-- To query real data change #TEST001 to your real table data. and TagA to your desired column.
declare @s DATETIME2 --Start date and time
declare @e DATETIME2 --End date and time
declare @i INT   -- Holds our desired interval. if you set to 60 you will get hour intervals, set to 1440 to get daily intervals.
                 -- set to 120 for every two hours
                 -- set to 2880 for every 2 days...
set @s = '2017-01-21 00:00:00.000'
set @e = '2017-01-21 23:59:59.000'
set @i = 60

--TIME GENERATOR, Generates all times between our start and end date.
;WITH ALL_INTERVALS
 AS (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@s,@e))
    TIMES = DATEADD(MINUTE,CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1),@s),
    NULL AS VALUE
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN
        sys.all_objects AS s2
),
--Union All possable times from our generator with all real data from our table.
ALL_TIMES
AS (
SELECT
        H.Time_Stamp as TIMES,
        H.TagA AS VALUE
    FROM @TEST001 H
    WHERE Time_Stamp BETWEEN @s and @e
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        AI.TIMES AS TIMES, 
        AI.VALUE AS VALUE
        FROM ALL_INTERVALS AI           
),
-- We need to fill across, up and down. 
-- TIMES=AT.TIMES, just inCASE our generated time is equal to our real data time.
-- TIMES>AT.TIMES Fill nulls in the upward dirrection.
-- TIMES>AT.TIMES Fill nulls in the downward dirrection.
FILL_UP_DOWN_ACCROSS 
AS ( 
    SELECT 
    TIMES AS TIMES, 
    VALUE AS VALUE1,
    ISNULL(AT.VALUE, (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM ALL_TIMES WHERE TIMES = AT.TIMES AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TIMES ASC)) AS VALUE2,
    ISNULL(AT.VALUE, (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM ALL_TIMES WHERE TIMES > AT.TIMES AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TIMES ASC)) AS VALUE3,
    ISNULL(AT.VALUE, (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM ALL_TIMES WHERE TIMES < AT.TIMES AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ORDER BY TIMES DESC)) AS VALUE4
    FROM ALL_TIMES AT
),
-- COMBINE, Select all non null values. The value1,2,3 can be removed! As they are not needed in the final select statement. 
-- I just have them here for quickly viewing what is going on if i make this COMBINE statement as my final select statement.
COMBINE 
AS (
SELECT TIMES,
        VALUE1,
        VALUE2,
        VALUE3,
        VALUE4,
        COALESCE( CASE WHEN FUDA.VALUE2 IS NULL AND FUDA.VALUE4 IS NULL THEN (FUDA.VALUE3) ELSE FUDA.VALUE2 END,
                  CASE WHEN FUDA.VALUE2 IS NULL AND FUDA.VALUE3 IS NULL THEN (FUDA.VALUE4) ELSE FUDA.VALUE2 END,
                  CASE WHEN FUDA.VALUE2 IS NULL AND FUDA.VALUE4 IS NOT NULL THEN (FUDA.VALUE4) ELSE FUDA.VALUE2 END
                  ) AS VALUE5
        FROM FILL_UP_DOWN_ACCROSS FUDA
)
--Final Select Statement, do the TWA! 
--DO TIME WEIGHED AVERAGE.
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@s,TIMES)/@i)*@i),@s) AS TIMES,
SUM( CONVERT(FLOAT,CAST(TIMES AS DATETIME)) * VALUE5) / SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,CAST(TIMES AS DATETIME))) AS TagAvg
FROM COMBINE
GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE,((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@s,TIMES)/@i)*@i),@s)
ORDER BY DATEADD(MINUTE,((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@s,TIMES)/@i)*@i),@s)
```